# Javascript For Loop How to?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to ask if I could do this:

Entering number 1 in textbox
Output is *

Entering number 10 in textbox
Output is **********

So the number must be equal to the number of stars.
Can someone help me with this because I'm not good in Javascript ?
I would appriciate it.

Kind Regards

Comment: what effort have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure that you would use a for loop for this?

Comment: Peter: a few colleagues of mine use the for loop.
Bub: I have some code:

var count = document.getElementById('inputTXT').value;  

  var star = "*";

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
 document.write(star + star);
 document.write(linebreak);
  }

  $(".outputTXT").html(count);

Comment: or `str = Array(number+1).join('*');`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is getting the value from the textbox and enter this into the for loop.

```
var value = document.getElementById('number').value
var text = ""
for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    text += "*";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
```

Here is more info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 0):

Enter your textBox output in variable input.

```
var str = "";
var input = 10;
    for(var i = 1; i <= input; i += 1) {
      str += "*";
    }
    console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this ..

```js
function printStar(count){
  for(var i=0; i < count; i++)
     document.write('*');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="printStar(this.value);">
```